# Strange behaviour with console.log() in the solution for LeetCode "2694. Event Emitter"

Tags: javascript, typescript

### Code

Here is my solution for the problem **[2694: EventEmitter](https://leetcode.com/problems/event-emitter/)**:

```js
type Callback = (...args: any[]) => any;
type Subscription = {
  unsubscribe: () => void;
};
type StampedCallback = { callback: Callback; timestamp: number };

class EventEmitter {
  events: Record<string, StampedCallback[]> = {};
  subscribe(eventName: string, callback: Callback): Subscription {
    if (!this.events[eventName]) this.events[eventName] = [];
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    this.events[eventName].push({ callback: callback, timestamp: timestamp });
    
    // Pay attention to this console.log() here
    console.log();
    
    return {
      unsubscribe: () => {
        this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName].filter(
          (stampedCallback) => stampedCallback.timestamp !== timestamp,
        );
      },
    };
  }

  emit(eventName: string, args: any[] = []): any[] {
    return (
      this.events[eventName]?.map(({ callback }) => callback(...args)) ?? []
    );
  }
}
```

and some test code

```js
const emitter = new EventEmitter();
const sub1 = emitter.subscribe("firstEvent", (x) => x + 1);
const sub2 = emitter.subscribe("firstEvent", (x) => x + 2);
sub1.unsubscribe(); // undefined
console.log("Output:", emitter.emit("firstEvent", [5])); // [7]
```

Here is the code in official **[TypeScriptPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=19&pln=13&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNZQLxQBQB0RcATgOYDOAXFHAHYgDaAugJQ4B8tDA3AFChIUAMoBXZBTQkAlmGDSA9nRxQA3nyhRRdCuMkzkEGnnbYuANwXSAJvwC+-QdGHA4AW0jX4SVJhWqoNEQUdAwabxDMHih5NwgKVw8aOlE3QxIoBz4+NAQ4CgooAFFzCDpgIrdpYGAIDPVNCFLy6igAJQg0BRJrAB4EmToyABoRRM8I3wwWLlxVLM1dCSlpQzwmsuAAOXcjKAHpIdGgn1Dw4KnWGjFlmTlFZQbNKGkAM3wAQmAAC2kKAg2LUYgO2uzYMV+-xBFGBzVBcWYKhY-GegSUCRi0jiCXcYBUABE4LUCHQFAB3Ewo54-P4AuEwkE7BEEMCiCjfPABE6RMKBC6hUaxeLjGhCnEeTKsKmaLo6BQICAEBAKMiUjTPEgQYCiEiPdWo7RLfSrPYmThqfWoiG06GwzZMiCI3A0qH0u3lB3MAivaQIWokPCWq34cUTfmYUxcUMQLzhjAEMXjKAfbDOrHC3HDIPPKXZuxZ1ELTLZRpVYDrOEOmgHI60citehMJ1QFhXbhNi2ozXa3X4bMuumbBmVsEAfgIbjgYDwnL5pz8dkjc55hGI9dY7FHo5bzEtuc0dj4h5y6OAUAgZf9KjoEDJxThlWq-rVsoxSwAjCoL0+6gQjSs1gAIh9EgEhKTZANGPAAA8l2gqAAGooHfXNXzPJYACYv0vX9-wMCA8GA6RQIqOFIPwWDzXgpCMNzD8CENPQAIIqUoAAejYrQ6GsCAfRvawTzlBUlRVQiAHlRGAVlgCocjvxqX95MIkCwLI0ZGAAVjYViOJbAB2XcgA)**

### My Question

For the code in the current state output on my machine is this:

```bash
Output: [ 7 ]
```

in playground:

```bash
[LOG]: 
[LOG]: 
[LOG]: "Output:",  [7]
```

As you can see, it outputs an array with 7 which is the correct output for this testcase

However, if I comment out the `console.log()` (line 13 in playground) I get:

```bash
Output: []
```

on my machine or:

```bash
[LOG]: "Output:",  []
```

in playground.
I do not understand, how can a single `console.log()` change the behaviour of the program this much. I also do not know how to reproduce the issue in simpler code.

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is that the `console.log()` introduces a little runtime delay. Without that, the timestamps for the two subscribers are the same, so unsubscribing from one removes them both from the array.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're observing is related to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript and how the console.log() affects the timing of execution. The issue is not with the EventEmitter implementation itself but with how console.log() impacts the asynchronous execution of the code.

Let's break down what's happening step by step:

1. When you have the console.log() statement in the code (line 13), it introduces a slight delay in execution, which allows the "firstEvent" callbacks to be successfully registered before they are executed.
2. With the console.log() statement present, the "firstEvent" callbacks (subscribers) are correctly added to the `events` object, and when you call `emitter.emit("firstEvent", [5])`, it triggers the callbacks, resulting in the correct output of `[7]`.
3. However, when you comment out the console.log() statement, the code executes faster since there is no delay introduced by the console.log(). This results in the "firstEvent" callbacks being registered and immediately removed (unsubscribed) before they have a chance to execute.

Let's see the sequence of events without the console.log():

- You call `emitter.subscribe("firstEvent", (x) => x + 1)`, and it adds the callback to `events["firstEvent"]` array.
- You call `emitter.subscribe("firstEvent", (x) => x + 2)`, and it adds the callback to `events["firstEvent"]` array.
- You call `sub1.unsubscribe()`, which removes the first callback you added earlier from the `events["firstEvent"]` array.
- Now, you call `emitter.emit("firstEvent", [5])`, but since the second callback (x => x + 2) was registered and removed before the emit call, it won't be executed, resulting in an empty array `[]`.

To address this issue, you might want to consider an alternative approach to delay the execution slightly, allowing the callbacks to be registered before the emit() call takes place. One way to do this is by using setTimeout() with a delay of 0:

```js
class EventEmitter {
  // ... (same implementation)

  subscribe(eventName: string, callback: Callback): Subscription {
    // ... (same implementation)

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(); // Introducing a slight delay
    });

    return {
      unsubscribe: () => {
        // ... (same implementation)
      },
    };
  }
}
```

By using setTimeout with a delay of 0, you ensure that the console.log() is executed asynchronously after the subscribe() function has finished its execution. This allows the callbacks to be registered before the emit() call takes place, giving you the correct output even without the console.log() statement.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments, the problem is that without `console.log()` both subscriptions happen "at the same time" so their timestamps are the same. So using `Date.now()` is most likely not a viable way to stamp callbacks. Here is an updated **[solution for the 2694 LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/event-emitter/submissions/1006255211/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=30-days-of-javascript)** that uses `Math.random()` instead.